# How does Bitvise SSH Server authenticate user without a password?

Tags: windows, winapi, authentication

Since version 5.50 the Bitvise SSH Server allows connected client to authenticate to Windows user account without providing this user's Windows password. See here: https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-version-history

I've checked it myself - it does indeed.

My question is of pure curiosity: what kind of sorcery is this? Is there any WinAPI that allows such thing or is this some kind of clever hack? I always thought it is impossible to impersonate as other user without a password (as even when configuring Windows service or scheduled task to "run as user" it is neccessary to provide one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the SSH server in Cygwin does the same thing.

If you have the appropriate privileges you can create an access token with ZwCreateToken, no password required.  Such a token has some limitations.  For example, you can't access network resources without a password and [some encrypted material isn't accessible](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290260).

There's an explanation and [some sample code here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6443/GUI-Based-RunAsEx).

Answer (score 1):

Since version 5.50, Bitvise SSH Server comes with a Windows authentication package. An authentication package can enhance the Windows logon process in custom ways. When the SSH server needs to log you in, but does not have a password (e.g. because you logged in with a public key), it calls the authentication package to construct a logon token which closely resembles the logon token that would have been created by Windows. As arx has noted, a session created this way does not contain your authentication credentials, so side effects are that you can't access things like network resources and EFS.

Comment: Any links to documentation about this? Thanks in advance.